# Como carregar api do google maps com uma rota para um endereço?

Tags: javascript, html, google

Instalei a api do Maps, porem não sei como chegar a um resultado, que seria carregar o mapa com a melhor rota entre dois endereços, estou usando javascript e html.

Answer (score 0):

adicione este código ao seu html:

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions
?key=SUA_API_KEY_AQUI&origin=endereco+de+origem&destination=endereco+do+destino&mode=driving" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Os seguintes parâmetros de URL são obrigatórios:

**origin:** define o ponto de partida a partir do qual exibir a rota. O valor pode ser o nome de um lugar, um endereço ou um ID de local. A string deve ter escape de URL. Isso significa que endereços como "City Hall, New York, NY" (Prefeitura, Nova York, NY) devem ser convertidos em City+Hall,New+York,NY. (A Google Maps Embed API permite + e %20 para escape de espaços.) IDs de local devem ser precedidos por place_id:.
destination define o ponto de chegada da rota.

Os seguintes parâmetros de URL são opcionais:

**waypoints:** especifica um ou mais locais intermediários para fornecer orientações de rota entre a origem e o destino. É possível especificar vários pontos de referência usando o caractere de barra vertical (|) para separar lugares (por exemplo: Berlin,Germany|Paris,France). Você pode especificar até 20 pontos de referência. Cada pontos de referência pode ser o nome de um lugar, um endereço ou um ID de local.

**mode:** define o modo de transporte. As opções são driving, walking (que dá preferência a vias para pedestres e calçadas, quando disponíveis), bicycling (que gera rotas por ciclovias e ruas preferenciais, quando disponíveis), transit ou flying. Se nenhum modo for especificado, a Google Maps Embed API mostrará um ou mais dos modos mais relevantes para a rota especificada.

**avoid:** instrui o Google Maps a evitar tolls, ferries e/ou highways. Separe valores com o caractere de barra vertical (por exemplo: avoid=tolls|highways). Observe que essa ação não exclui rotas que incluam os componentes restritos; ela simplesmente direciona o resultado para rotas mais favoráveis.

**units:** especifica unidades metric ou imperial ao exibir distâncias nos resultados. Se units não forem especificadas, o país de origin da consulta determinará as unidades usadas.

Você pode utilizar o javascript para mudar o valor da "origin" e "destination" dinamicamente ;)

fonte: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide?hl=pt-br#optional_parameters